# Truly a beginner, assigning the multiple values to one variable in Python

Tags: python, jython, jes

I want to make an image for any user, that's not specific to one size, I came up with this. I'm new at this, can anyone let me know why this does not work?

```
blk = makeEmptyPicture(getWidth(pic)+30), getHeight(pic)+30), black)
```

Comment: Details on what you mean by "does not work" please.

Comment: I think he's trying to use a tuple (or maybe a dictionary for associative keys) given the title.  Whether the OP actually needs to do that I'm not certain from the one line of code and description provided.

Answer (score 6):

**blk = makeEmptyPicture`(`getWidth`(`pic`)`+30`)`, getHeight`(`pic`)`+30`)`, black`)`**

It probably doesn't work because your parens aren't balanced. You have 3 open-parens and 5 close-parens.

Perhaps this is what you meant instead?

```
blk = makeEmptyPicture(getWidth(pic)+30, getHeight(pic)+30, black)
```

Comment: Adding spaces and counting "(" and then counting ")" is how its done!  (OR: Using an IDE w/ syntax highlighting!)

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
blk = makeEmptyPicture((getWidth(pic)+30), (getHeight(pic)+30), black)
```

Comment: The extra parens around each argument are redundant.

Comment: yes. i know that. it was just for him to understand better :)